# Variable is cleared on PostExecute event SSIS 2008

Tags: variables, ssis, execute

I am trying to pass Package variable: packno from Execute SQL Task to Data flow.
Variable is filled with needed value on [OnProgress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQPkp.jpg) event. The value is:20717.
But on [OnPostExecute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upTgA.jpg) event this value is cleared and assigned: -1.

So SQL command is executed with -1 value. 
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: check code so variable is getting re-st /overwritten   and check if EvaluateAsExpression  is true or not..

Comment: Is the variable's value a result of a query within the Execute SQL Task?

Comment: EvaluateAsExpression is set to false. Yes, the variable's value is a result of query and it's assigned fine on the progress stage. Something happens after. There is not any custom code

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the server. Everything worked fine on different one.